# Почему нельзя перегрузить оператор << в класcе?

Tags: c++

Нашел вот это "Действительно, ни функция вставки, ни функция извлечения не могут быть членами класc­а. Причина заключается в том, что если функция-оператор является членом класса, то левым операндом, неявно передаваемым с использованием указателя this, служит объект того класса, который осуществляет вызов функции-оператора.". Что-то то я не понял эти слова. Могли бы вы как нибудь поподробней объяснить или же на примере следующего кода, показать как бы это работало, если бы оператор << был членом функции.

```
#include <iostream.h>
class three_d {
public:
int x, y, z;
three_d(int a, int b, int c) { x=a; y=b; z=c; }
};
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, three_d obj)
{
stream << obj.x << ", ";
stream << obj.у << ", ";
stream << obj.z << "\n";
return stream;
}
int main()
{
three_d a(1, 2, 3), b(3, 4, 5), c(5, 6, 7);
cout << a << b << c;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: добавь как "друга" тогда указателя **`this`** небудет... (подробности погугли)

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, three_d obj)



а так же лучше передавай объект по ссылке...

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, three_d &obj)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну смотрите. Допустим, у вас есть оператор, который вызывается так:

```
x << y;
```

где объекты `x` и `y` имеют тип `X` и `Y` соответственно.

Определить такой оператор можно следующими путями:

Первый вариант: внутри класса `X`

```
class X
{
public:
    X& operator << (const Y& y); // или другой возвращаемый тип, как вам нравится
};
```

Второй вариант: без всякого класса

```
X& operator << (X& x, const Y& y);
```

Определить оператор в классе `Y` вы не сможете, поскольку декларация

```
class Y
{
public:
    X& operator << (const X& x);
};
```

определит оператор, который вызывается так:

```
y << x;
```

Для вашего случая, `X` -- это `std::ostream`, `Y` -- `three_d`. Добавить определение в `ostream` по первому варианту вы не сможете, потому что этот класс уже полностью определён. Так что осталась возможность работать только по второму варианту.

Comment: [@VladD][1], Спасибо. Ну а третий вариант [вот][2] , не логично конечно, вот только не пойму почему стек переполняется, если вставить в поток объекты вместо полей объекта, вот [пример][3]. И причем тут вообще стек. Наверное я не понимаю это, потому что так и не понял что такое поток, ссылки [1][4] и [2][5] ничего не прояснили, там для меня очень много непонятных слов и нет ассоциаций с чем то. Вот задал новый [вопрос][6] по поводу потоков.
  [1]: http://u.to/dsYBAw
  [2]: http://u.to/isYBAw
  [3]: http://u.to/osYBAw
  [4]: http://u.to/18QBAw
  [5]: http://u.to/_cQBAw
  [6]: http://u.to/I8UBAw

Comment: @mzarb: хе :) вот этот код неправильный:

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const three_d& obj)
    {
        stream << obj << ", ";
        stream << obj << ", ";
        stream << obj << "\n";
        return stream;
    }

Потому что `stream << obj` -- это же вызов `operator<<(ostream& stream, const three_d& obj)`, то есть рекурсивный вызов этой же самой функции.

Comment: @VladD, Ясно:). Ещё кое-что, оператор вставки будет перегружаться и при `stream << obj.x`, то есть в классе `ostream` есть перегруженная версия, которая выполнит этот код `stream << obj.x`? Если нет, то не понятно куда и как вставляется значения `obj.x`.

Comment: @mzarb: в MS Visual Studio класс `basic_ostream` (родительский класс `ostream`) действительно определяет операторы `<<` для базовых типов. Не уверен насчёт остальных компиляторов, может быть они имеют право определить и функцию с двумя аргументами.